# How to extract only month, day and year portion of datetime from DateTime string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, display-templates

I'm writing DateTime Formatter in ASP.NET MVC and need to format the datetime based on cultural info.

My model's property binds `DateTime.Now` volue to the view and as a result the view is displaying `3/21/2017 9:38:37 AM` as a datetime.

I'm looking for the way to display 3/21/2017 or 21/3/2017 and etc based on the culture.

What is the best way to do it. I tried a few examples from

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

```
<span>String.Format("{0:d}", @Model.ToString())</span>
```

But the view still display the full datetime value: `3/21/2017 9:38:37 AM`

I know that might be easy question but anywhere need some input on that.

What is the best way to handle something like that?

Answer (score 0):

C# has come helpers built into the DateTime class. You can do this to only get the date.

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Or using your code assuming mode is an instance of DateTime:

```
@Model.ToShortDateString()
```